# Ruby builder xml

Tags: ruby, xml, builder, zuora

I am using Builder to create xml in Ruby. It works fine when I call the generate_object method twice. However, when doing it in a loop I am getting some weird results. The input is the same both times.

Here is the code.

```
def generate_xml
    xml = Builder::XmlMarkup.new

  #this doesn't work
  #objects.each do |o|
  #  generate_object xml, o
  #end
  #this works...
  generate_object(xml, objects[0])
  generate_object(xml, objects[1])          
end
def generate_object(builder, object)
    builder.__send__('ins0', :zObjects, 'xsi:type' => "ins1:account") do |a|
        object.to_hash.each do |k,v|
            #puts "key #{k} #{v}!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!"
            a.__send__('ins1', k.to_s.zuora_camelize.to_sym, v) unless v.nil?
        end
    end
end
```

Looping through the objects prints:

```
<env:Body>
  <ins0:create>
    [#<Zuora::Objects::Account:0x007fcd69d61788 
      @changed_attributes={
        "auto_pay"=>nil, 
        "currency"=>nil, 
        "batch"=>nil, 
        "bill_cycle_day"=>nil, 
        "status"=>nil, 
        "payment_term"=>nil, 
        "name"=>nil
      },
      @auto_pay=false, 
      @currency="USD", 
      @batch="Batch1", 
      @bill_cycle_day=1, 
      @status="Draft", 
      @payment_term="Due Upon Receipt", 
      @name="test">, 
    #<Zuora::Objects::Account:0x007fcd69d60d10 
      @changed_attributes={
        "auto_pay"=>nil, 
        "currency"=>nil, 
        "batch"=>nil, 
        "bill_cycle_day"=>nil, 
        "status"=>nil, 
        "payment_term"=>nil, 
        "name"=>nil
      }, 
      @auto_pay=false, 
      @currency="USD", 
      @batch="Batch1", 
      @bill_cycle_day=1, 
      @status="Draft", 
      @payment_term="Due Upon Receipt", 
      @name="test 2">
    ]
  </ins0:create>
</env:Body>
```

Executing the two calls without a loop:

```
<env:Body>
  <ins0:create>
    <ins0:zObjects xsi:type="ins1:account">
      <ins1:AutoPay>false</ins1:AutoPay>
      <ins1:Batch>Batch1</ins1:Batch>
      <ins1:BillCycleDay>1</ins1:BillCycleDay>
      <ins1:Currency>USD</ins1:Currency>
      <ins1:Name>test</ins1:Name>
      <ins1:PaymentTerm>Due Upon Receipt</ins1:PaymentTerm>
      <ins1:Status>Draft</ins1:Status>
    </ins0:zObjects>
    <ins0:zObjects xsi:type="ins1:account">
      <ins1:AutoPay>false</ins1:AutoPay>
      <ins1:Batch>Batch1</ins1:Batch>
      <ins1:BillCycleDay>1</ins1:BillCycleDay>
      <ins1:Currency>USD</ins1:Currency>
      <ins1:Name>test 2</ins1:Name>
      <ins1:PaymentTerm>Due Upon Receipt</ins1:PaymentTerm>
      <ins1:Status>Draft</ins1:Status>
    </ins0:zObjects>
  </ins0:create>
</env:Body>
```

Comment: What is going wrong when your run it in a loop? Saying you get weird results will not help people figure out the problem.

Comment: If I'm interpreting it correctly, the weird result is that using a loop prints the `o.inspect` output (first output), while explicitly sending each object gives the xml representation (second output). Is that correct?

Comment: Yea, sorry. In the case where it is looping through the objects. It is printing something similar to object.inspect. The XML is being generated correctly when I call the method twice without the loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you are just getting the output of .each muddled up with what you want to return.

Try:

```
def generate_xml
  xml = Builder::XmlMarkup.new

  objects.each do |o|
    generate_object xml, o
  end
  # Return the builder object, not the output of .each (the list of objects)!
  xml
end
```